# Filter git diff to show two folders with M and A

Tags: git

I am trying to use git diff to show only 2 particular folder paths.  This errors.

```
git diff cfa/ && pma/ --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD~5 HEAD
```

Comment: you want to diff the content of path each other or show only diff in thoses directories

Comment: What do you mean with _This errors_? Does fail with an error message? If so, what message? Does it give a wrong output? If so, what does it give and what do you expect?

Comment: BTW `&&` seems lost in there

Comment: I want to get a list of all files that were modified or added between HEAD~5 and HEAD. However the only directories I want to see this from are cfa/ and pma/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the `&&` has little to do here and you are trying to write:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM HEAD~5 HEAD -- cfa/ pma/
```